# Get a Count of month year Record for Certain Label and Replace a Value in Another Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called "ticketManager" in my mssql. There were some expenses missing for "ABC" and I got monthly expenses. I want to divide it equally base on the count of Signed_Date.

```sql
Event_ID Name   ticket  Revenue Expences    expect  Signed_Date 
G-00001  ABC    671     6720    0           50       01 June 2021   
G-00002  CSA    5       56      18          100      05 June 2021   
G-00003  CSA    5       78      38          100      03 June 2021   
G-00004  VSX    23      34      23          NaN      03 June 2021   
G-00005  ABC    4       89      0           40       02 June 2021   
G-00006  ABC    60      73      0           60       15 April 2021  
G-00007  CSA    60      345     110         60       12 June 2021   
G-00008  ABC    89      890     NaN         NaN      02 June 2021   
G-00009  VSX    0       0       0           50       30 April 2021  
G-00010  CSA    6       45      16          60       22 June 2021   
G-00011  VSX    3       39      23          30       10 June 2021   
G-00012  ABC    2       34      0           20       03 June 2021   
G-00013  VSX    4       89      48          40       12 June 2021   
G-00014  VSX    32      127     35          10       24 April 2021  
G-00015  ABC    3       84      0           120      21 April 2021  
G-00016  ABC    1       100     0           140      7 June 2021    
G-00017  CSA    23      525                 90       02 April 2021
```

for example, in June I have 5 records for ABC and I have expenses as 750.00. So I want to place 150 (750/5) for each record same as for April I have expenses as 110 and have 2 records. So want to place 55 for each record in ABC.

So the table looks like below.

```
Event_ID Name   ticket  Revenue Expences    expect  Signed_Date 
G-00001  ABC    671     6720    150         50       01 June 2021   
G-00002  CSA    5       56      18          100      05 June 2021   
G-00003  CSA    5       78      38          100      03 June 2021   
G-00004  VSX    23      34      23          NaN      03 June 2021   
G-00005  ABC    4       89      150         40       02 June 2021   
G-00006  ABC    60      73      55          60       15 April 2021  
G-00007  CSA    60      345     110         60       12 June 2021   
G-00008  ABC    89      890     150         NaN      02 June 2021   
G-00009  VSX    0       0       0           50       30 April 2021  
G-00010  CSA    6       45      16          60       22 June 2021   
G-00011  VSX    3       39      23          30       10 June 2021   
G-00012  ABC    2       34      150         20       03 June 2021   
G-00013  VSX    4       89      48          40       12 June 2021   
G-00014  VSX    32      127     35          10       24 April 2021  
G-00015  ABC    3       84      55          120      21 April 2021  
G-00016  ABC    1       100     150         140      7 June 2021    
G-00017  CSA    23      525                 90       02 April 2021
```

I have like million reords like that and have 5 years woth of records. What would be the efficience way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function:

```
SELECT t.*, avg(Expences) over (partition by extract(year_month from Signed_Date))
FROM ticketManager t;
```